# CSS - drop-shadow not working properly in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I have added a `drop-shadow` filter on an image on my site. It is working properly in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari.

I tried following code:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
  list-style: outside none none;
}
.tabed_setting_div a > img {
   filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #000);
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #000);
  -moz-filter:  drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #000);
  -ms-filter:  drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #000);
  -o-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #000);
}
```

Please see [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpg97xcj/2/) for a demo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safari's drop shadow is very small compared to Chrome's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991747/safaris-drop-shadow-is-very-small-compared-to-chromes)

Comment: I just opened your fiddle inside safari mac os and the shadow is displaying, just with a lesser gradient fade. Link to Firefox (left) and Safari (right) https://postimg.org/gallery/1mxu4cwg2/9bd9dfd5/

Comment: i could not see.. is this because of version problem??

Comment: @Leo the lion that changes is also not working in my code.

Comment: link to both firefox and safari screen caps https://postimg.org/gallery/1mxu4cwg2/9bd9dfd5/

Comment: What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: i used 5.1.7 version

Comment: They stopped updating and adding new versions to Windows Safari years ago. This is your issue.

Comment: OK. @Aaron Thanks for reply..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Windows, Safari version on Windows is way behind the current Safari version for Mac.

- On Windows, the current Safari version is 5.1, in Mac its 9.1 (Latest Release).
- Safari 5.1 does not support the filter style, In my perspective you shouldn't have to concern about it because most of the users aren't using Safari in Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your answere

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally there are issues in the way Safari chooses to render the drop-shadow filter. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Internally, Safari does some calculations to decide whether to run the filter on the cpu or the gpu. Based on overflow or layout choices, it may incorrectly choose the cpu.

**To fix this behaviour:**

In TailwindCSS you can add the `transform-gpu` to force the rendering to properly occur on the gpu. Then it will appear as it would in Chrome.

Another tag that would work is `backdrop-blur-0` (`backdrop-filter: blur(0);` in css), as Safari will always run the filtering on the gpu with this filter present.

[Link to relevant GitHub Issue with photos of rendering differences](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/issues/17726).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `will-change: filter;` works pretty well for me.

Answer (score -2):

Safari supports drop shadow filter for the version 9.1. Update your Safari, Issue will be automatically resolved.

See

- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: This isnt a solution for developers, only for end users